# Lost Global Privileges on root@localhost in PHPMyAdmin (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi all and please help

I have been running XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin for a number of years on my PC.  Both have served me well.

This morning I got an warning message basically saying give root a password because it was not secure.  I did (or thought I had), but as a result Now all I can view is a database called information_schema.

I initially panicked, but then found that all my other test sites are working ok and I can still access them via their own username and password.

Therefore my question is: Please could anyone tell me how I can grant Global Privileges back on root@localhost?  I have tried a number of things all morning but I get greeted either with a Syntax problem or a 1045 error message, saying Access Denied.

I welcome any help or advice.  On the bright side, I have a password for root now!

Comment: Before you do anything else, **did you install another instance of MySQL** since you last used XAMPP as it sounds like it is connecting to another fresh install of MySQL.

Comment: Possibly.  All i get is the Information Schema database and can log into all my other databases which their specified username and password. On that only database it insists I have no privileges so can't create a fresh database and no control over Users or other databases.

Comment: Or would it just be easier if I reinstalled XAMPP/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Thats wont fix the issue of 2 MySQL Servers on the same PC

Comment: Ok.  How do I check?  How can I resolve this? I am great at following clear instructions.  Please help.

Comment: WindowsKey+R, keyin `services.msc` Not sure if xampp renames its MySQL service, but look in the list of services for more than one MYSQL service

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly.  I have had a bit more time today and have pondered over your answers.  I can honestly say that I have not installed any other MySQL program on my PC.  All I have done is tried to add a password onto root@localhost in PHPmyAdmin (on my localhost/) and tried to add a password.  Now my once before global login is now not very global at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the password on the `root` userid from within phpMyAdmin, you then have to put that password into the phpMyAdmin config.

So edit \xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

Find this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

and add the password to it

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NEW_PASSWORD';
```

Comment: Ok.  I done that.  How can I reset root@localhost the privileges it once had?

Comment: `root` should already have the `super user` privilages, unless you did more than just try and add a password to it using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: As I said before, all I can access is the information_schema from the root and that is all. So I clearly have done something very wrong. When i access Database next to Create databases it says 'No Privileges' below it. I tried a couple of things yesterday and kept getting the #1045 Access Denied for user root@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Sorted.  In my case, I discovered that I had another global login and from the User list, I was able to grant global privileges for the root login once again